# Replace special characters from IDs with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have e. g. this code:

```
<article role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="2.asdasdasdda">
```

and need to delete/replace the "." in the IDs.

I tried with:

```
$('.tab-pane').replace('.','LEAVE');
```

but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use `$('.tab-pane').attr("id").replace('.','')` instead

Comment: A `.` is a valid character in an `id` - in HTML5 at least. You would be better to remove them from the source directly if needed. You can quite easily escape the characters in jQuery selectors if that's your concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reassign the value of `ID` attribute.

```js
$('.tab-pane').attr('id', function(_, value) {
  return value.replace('.', 'LEAVE');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="2.asdasdasdda">aaa</article>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use it this way:

```
$('.tab-pane').attr('id', function(){
   var id = this.id.replace('.','LEAVE');
   return id;
});
```

> *but nothing happens.*

Surely! Your code won't work at you are trying to replace the `.` of the element's contents which is not the case.
Because you want to change an attribute `id` of it. So, `.attr()` method can be used with a function as a second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (of course you can change "leave" with what you want):

```js
console.log($(".tab-pane").attr("id"));
$(".tab-pane").attr("id",$('.tab-pane').attr("id").replace('.','LEAVE'));
console.log($(".tab-pane").attr("id"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="2.asdasdasdda">
```